# Hashmap to implement adjacency lists

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I've implement an adjacency list using the **vector of vectors** approach with the nth element of the vector of vectors refers to the friend list of node n.

I was wondering if the **hash map** data structure would be more useful. I still have hesitations because I simply cannot identify the difference between them and for example if I would like to check and do an operation in nth elements neighbors (search,delete) how could it be more efficient than the vector of vectors approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `vector<vector<ID>>` is a good approach if the set of nodes is fixed. If however you suddenly decide to remove a node, you'll be annoyed. You cannot shrink the vector because it would displace the elements stored after the node and you would lose the references. On the other hand, if you keep a list of free (reusable) IDs on the side, you can just "nullify" the slot and then reuse later. Very efficient.

A `unordered_map<ID, vector<ID>>` allows you to delete nodes much more easily. You can go ahead and assign new IDs to the newly created nodes and you will not be losing empty slots. It is not as compact, especially on collisions, but not so bad either. There can be some slow downs on rehashing when a vector need be moved with older compilers.

Finally, a `unordered_multimap<ID, ID>` is probably one of the easiest to manage. It also scatters memory to the wind, but hey :)

Personally, I would start prototyping with a `unordered_multimap<ID, ID>` and switch to another representation only if it proves too slow for my needs.

*Note: you can cut in half the number of nodes if the adjacency relationship is symmetric by establishing than the relation `(x, y)` is stored for `min(x, y)` only.*

Answer (score 0):

## Vector of vectors

Vector of vectors is good solution when you don't need to delete edges.

You can add edge in O(1), you can iterate over neighbours in O(N).
You can delete edge by `vector[node].erase(edge)` but it will be slow, complexity only O(number of vertices).

## Hash map

I am not sure how you want to use hash map. If inserting edge means setting `hash_map[edge] = 1` then notice that you are unable to iterate over node's neighbours.

Comment: Vector of vectors a horrible solution if you need to remove *nodes* because you will end up renumbering part of the nodes, then scan all edges to fix the node numbers.  Removing edges is easy, just use the erase-remove idiom on a single vector to remove a specific edge.

Comment: @AndréCaron: not necessarily. You can simply "nullify" the slot and reuse later when you add back a new node.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I would avoid that for two reasons.  First, you'll have no way to distinguish between that slot representing a vertex with no outbound edges and a "null" slot.  Second, if you're removing nodes on a regular basis, you'll end up with a nasty sparse data structure.  The approach described in your answer is much better for dynamic graph structures.